# Покончил с собой / Покончил собой

Tags: фразеология

«Покончил собой» — это словосочетание при огромном перевесе упоминаний в НКРЯ фразеологизма «Покончил с собой» — вызывает вопросы: можно ли считать его фразеологизмом? и на какой вопрос отвечает слово ***собой***?

Comment: Если два вопроса связаны вопросительной интонацией, то запятая между ними не нужна (в случае с И).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой В примерах Розенталя вопросы связаны между собой по смыслу — общая тема (*1. время; 2. конференция; 3. кому прийти*). А здесь вопросы совсем разные.

Comment: @oleedd: конференция? В любом случае, если вопросительная интонация связывает вопросы, запятая не нужна.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Повестка дня [конференции]. Если вопросы разные, они не читаются без паузы. Другое дело, что часть до двоеточия общая для вопросов — весомый аргумент, чтобы не ставить запятую.

Comment: @oleedd: найдите правило, по которому нужна запятая при вопросительной интонации обеих частей хотя бы без общей части.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Розенталь формулировал правила, исходя из примеров. Примеры из литературы — главное.

Comment: Не обязательно Розенталь. Кто оправдывает постановку запятой в данном случае? В примерах (в Нацкорпусе) могут быть ошибки.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Кто оправдывает? — Здравый смысл.

Comment: Меня интересуют правила.

Answer (score 1):

Факт такого написания в некоторых книгах (их нашёлся добрый десяток) для меня стал неожиданностью. Такое впечатление, что это выражение некоторыми авторами усваивалось из устной речи. Ни у Даля, ни в более поздних словарях это беспредложное словосочетание не встречается. Беспредложный вариант нормативен лишь при употреблении глагола в переходном значении (покончить что  - вместо "покончить **с** чем, кем").

Comment: "покончить что" — а есть пример?

Comment: Покончить дело миром (из Ушакова) - в значении "завершить, довести до конца". https://gufo.me/dict/ushakov/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Не слышал такого. Думаю, что сейчас так не говорят (без предлога). Как-то оно старинно звучит. Уже Кузнецов отмечает, и лишь в подпункте "оттенок значения", что без предлога реже. Для этого есть другой глагол - закончить.

Comment: Тем не менее, выражение литературное, на его фоне "покончить собой" воспринимается как ошибка корректора или программы оптического распознавания текста.

Comment: Есть "покончить самоубийством", а тут, думаю, решили сделать сокращение по аналогии.

Comment: Это сокращение от _беспредложного_ "покончить (жизнь) самоубийством" - аналогии не просматривается. Предлог же можно "сократить" при записи под диктовку вполне грамотного автора.

Comment: Имею в виду, что по аналогии с фразой, в которой нет предлога. Не понял, какой предлог можно сократить. Эта фраза употребляется без предлога.

Comment: Обязательный предлог "с" в выражении "покончить **с** собой" (разобраться с кем, с чем).

Comment: Это да. Тогда *"сократить" при записи под диктовку вполне грамотного автора* — не знаю, кто и зачем "сможет" его сократить по каким-то соображениям. Это какой-то выпадающий из логики случай.